# Adding javascript files to Yeoman webapp generated website

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I am playing with the yoman trying to build a web site using the webapp generator.

If Managed to create a web site that works under grunt server, when I change a js file grunt notices the change change and does a live load and everything works as you would expect.

When I try a plan grunt, it attempts to run the dist task, it manages to include my html files,  but skips any of the javascript or script files I created in the script and styles diretores.  I assume its the case I have to tell grunt to includes these files

Files such as main.js seem to make it through, but there are no references to main.js in the Gruntfile, so I not sure which part of Gruntfile.js to change.

Doing a yo doctor reports 
[Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks all right!

Q. How to do I tell grunt to include and user created files.

Q. I noticed that all my image files where renamed, fair enough how do I refer to a file that I known is going to be renamed in a javascript file

Q. Does anybody known a good web resource for yoman where these quesion might have already been answered?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your actual gruntfile/whatever else Yeoman generates? It's difficult to tell exactly what the problem might be without more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful on this glob pattern `scripts/{,*}/*.js`. This takes only the js files that are inside scripts or immediate child folders.

Make sure to change it to `scripts/**/*.js` to include all js files in all subfolders.

Also get an idea on tags `build: css`, `build: js` in your index.html, `wiredep` plugin used by Yeoman in gruntfile to understand what files will be injected into dist folder.

Comment: Thanks Vamshi for a swift response.  Do I have to include links such as
 
<!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/foo.js -->
<script src="scripts/foo.js type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- endbuild --> 
to get it to work ?

Comment: Ya.. these are the tags used by `wiredep` grunt task when extracting all the js files to your dist directory.

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-usemin for full comments on wiredep, out of the bucket it only does js and css